# Piping 2 grep commands into wc

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, grep, word-count

I have a file called *a.txt* that is 100 lines long.

```
grep    rake a.txt | wc    #returns 10 lines

grep -v rake a.txt | wc    #returns 90 lines

grep    Rake a.txt | wc    #returns  3 lines
```

one of these 100 lines has both, but I want lines with *only* 'Rake'. I have tried `grep Rake a.txt | grep -v rake a.txt | wc` returns 90 lines?

I want to find all 3 lines with 'Rake', pipe it into `grep`, find if any of those 3 lines include 'Rake' but not 'rake', and then use `wc` to count the lines that do. I could use redirect to make another file and then `grep -v` that new file, but that's not really my goal here. I'm sure it's something simple, but how do I fix my command?

Comment: Some sample input and the expected output would be useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried `grep Rake a.txt | grep -v rake a.txt | wc` returns 90 lines?

The point of piping is that the output of a command feeds the next one. Instead, you are piping and then saying `grep -v rake a.txt`, which makes the previous command superfluous.

So you just need to pipe normally:

```
grep Rake a.txt | grep -v rake   | wc
#                              ^
#                             removed a.txt
```

You can also use `awk` and tell it to count lines containing *Rake*, not *rake*. Finally, print the counter:

```
awk '/Rake/ && !/rake/ {count++} END {print count+0}' a.txt
```

Comment: I will have to look into using awk. I am very new to using the terminal and currently learning the basics through some online resources. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @Aaron you are welcome :) Welcome also to the UNIX world, were you will discover many interesting stuff.

Comment: Why not use grep -c instead of piping to wc?

Comment: @VarunM that's a good hint. `grep Rake a.txt | grep -vc rake` would make it. Anyway, I would go for the `awk` approach.

Answer (score 2):

Don't give a file argument to the second `grep`, i.e.:

```
grep Rake a.txt | grep -v rake | wc -l
```

With the file argument, `grep` will search the file again. Without it, it will just filter its input.

Comment: This is nice to know. The online lessons I'm currently taking kindly excluded this fun fact when introducing grep & piping